# "Segmentation fault" error on Raspberry Pi 4 python spidev with MCP3008

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, segmentation-fault, spi, raspberry-pi4

I get the "Segmentation fault" error every time I start the following script.
SPI is enabled and the MCP3008 chip is wired correctly.

```
import spidev
import time
import csv
import datetime as dt

spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0, 1)
spi.max_speed_hz = 5000

writer = csv.writer(open("data.csv", "w"))
writer.writerow(["time", "voltage", "current", "power"])

def get_time():

    tm = dt.datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%Y-%H:%M")

    return tm

def get_voltage():

    answerV = spi.xfer(1,128,0)

    if 0 <= answerV[1] <= 3:
        voltage_measurement = ((((answerV[1] * 256) + answerV[2]) * 0.00322) * 90) // 40
        print(voltage_measurement, " V")

return voltage_measurement

def get_current():

    answerC = spi.xfer(1,176,0)

    if 0 <= answerC[1] <= 3:
        current_measurement = ((answerC[1] * 256) + answerC[2]) * 0.00322 * 0.066
        print(current_measurement, " A")

    if ((answerC[1] * 256) + answerC[2]) * 0.00322 == 2:
        current_measurement = 0

    return current_measurement

def get_power(v, i):

    power = (v * i)

    return power

while True:
    tm = get_time()
    i = get_current()
    v = get_voltage()
    writer.writerow([tm, v, i, p])

    time.sleep(1)
```

I tried running the script and expected it to write the voltage, current, power and the time they were measured in the .csv file every second.
The mathematics in every function are for calculating the output to the desired data.
I think there is nothing wrong with the other part of the code, because the script wont even start.

Comment: There is a syntax error in the indentation of the "return voltage_measurement" line in the get_voltage() function. But maybe it is simply a mistake while copying the snippet..



Additionally, there is a typo error in the writer.writerow([tm, v, i, p]) line where p is not defined. You must add a get_power(v, i) line to fix the issue

Comment: Thank you, I tried that but it didn't work :(

Comment: The segmentation fault is probably from something spidev does. Would be easier to help if you could run this with gdb and post the backtrace.

Comment: Why don't you use the Linux kernel driver for MCP3008?